# MVC 3 Web form textbox defaults to value=0, how to make it blank

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I have a site that was created with VS2010 MVC 3 (by someone else), the partial code as follows...

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.IdNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.IdNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.IdNumber)
        </div>
```

...when the page is rendered in a browser you get...

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="IdNumber">Id Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id Number must be a number." data-val-required="The Id Number field is required." id="IdNumber" name="IdNumber" type="text" value="0" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="IdNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

...the textbox is pre-filled with a 0, and users have to delete that to enter their own ID which never starts with a 0, how can I make that blank.  I think I need to remove the value="0" but everything I've searched for does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Make the IdNumber a nullable Int. It gets the default value of an int right now (0)

Comment: In my model I put...
        <Display(Name:="Id Number")>
        <Required()>
        Public Property IdNumber As Nullable(Of Integer)
...but that doesn't seem to do the trick?  Should I be adding this somewhere else?

Comment: I would check that noting sets it to a value of 0

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property IdNumberString to your model and bind to that property instead. And make your IdNumberString to return an empty string or null value when you have no value (or 0 value) in your DB.